# How to jump to a particular preference when starting a preference activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a `PreferenceActivity` to which I add preferences from an xml file using

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences).
```

When I start my `PreferenceActivity` I am taken to the top of the preference hierarchy, (as expected).

I would now like to have a shortcut button from my main activity to a  preference lower in the preferences.xml file hierarchy.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to customize anything. If your target is lower than Honeycomb (3.0), then use this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:title="Settings" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Category 1" >
        <PreferenceScreen android:title="Display" >
            ...
```

Every `<PreferenceScreen>` will be loaded into an activity automatically.

If your target is 3.x+, you can refer to samples inside Android SDK folder.